# My Models Are Not Appearing The Shading Tab [SOLVED]

Tags: mesh, shaders

My models are not appearing in the shading tab only the models I downloaded online are visible that must mean I did something wrong but don't know what. I also pressed  <kbd>.</kbd> key on numpad after selecting the objects but nothing happens

This is layout tab
[image: This is layout tab]

This is the shading tab as you can see only the models I downloaded are visible
[image: This is the shading tab as you can see only the models I downloaded are visible]

Comment: It’s odd that the walls you modeled are not visible, but I’m not sure you fully understand how materials/shaders and objects are related. Do the walls you modeled have just the default material, or did you change something?

Comment: You're in *Local View* which only displays the selected models (screenshot 2). Press the `Numpad /` (divide) or select the menu entry *View > Local View > Toggle Local View* to get out.

Comment: Blunder Thanks so much that solved the problem. Now I feel so stupid that the problem which I thought to be big was so small

Comment: @Blunder Thank you, too.